# JW6 event - EventListener

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to find out how can I get the event state

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
file: "1.mp4"
});
```

I want to know what is the status

play
paused
ended

Answer (score 0):

Under your player set up, add this script block, it has all the base events and some alerts:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer().onReady(function() { alert('Player is ready'); });
 jwplayer().onPlay(function() { alert('Player is playing'); });
 jwplayer().oPause(function() { alert('Player is paused'); });
 jwplayer().onComplete(function() { alert('Playback is complete'); });
</script>
```